# How to concatenate variable and string in laravel

Tags: php

i want to concatinate select_teacherActivity with variable $week_no and variable $activity as one word

```
 $Activity->description = $request->input('select_teacherActivity".$week_no.".$activity');
```

Comment: how can i do that concatenation?

Comment: Use + for variables and dot for string

Comment: You could change `input('select_teacherActivity".$week_no.".$activity');` to `input("select_teacherActivity$week_no$activity");` (in double quotes)

Answer (score 5):

if you want get a string you should use concat operation '.' `'select_teacherActivity".$week_no . $activity;`
this should work if `$week_no` and `$activity` sting or there have implemented toString magic method.

Comment: Thank you for the simple, non-judgemental answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple syntax errors in the code shared:

All opening quotes should close with the corresponding type of quote:

```
'select_teacherActivity" //Wrong
'select_teacherActivity' //Right
.". //Wrong
."".//Right (but unnecessary)
```

There is also have a stray `'` at the end.
Full code:

```
$Activity->description = $request->input('select_teacherActivity'.$week_no.$activity);
```